# How can i get/set the public URL to my Calendar?

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

I need a hint to set this via API ...

[image]

And how can I get the public URL via API?

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Best regards

Bernd

Comment: Unfortunately your image arnt in English and i'm not sure what you mean by public url?    Could you be a little more clear?  Have you checked the documentation,  I haven heard of anything related to a public url so not sure you would find anything in the documentation about it.

Answer (score 0):

### For sharing calendars via Google Calendar API:

- You can use the method [Acl: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/acl/insert) that allows you to create an Access Control List rule.
- You can define

> role

> scope.type

and

> scope.value

Sample request body:

```
{
  "role": "reader",
  "scope": {
    "type": "default"
  }
}
```

For more detailed information please read [Sharing and Attendees](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/sharing)